# Leaving behind just numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I have a column in Google Sheets that has phone numbers with the following formats:

1. (904) 123 4567
2. +62 123 4567
3. +12345678

How can I create another column that automatically removes "+", "(", ")" and spaces to produce 9041234567?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `REGEXREPLACE` to remove the characters you don't want:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[ \(\)\+]"; "")`

[image: solution working]

The expression used `[ \(\)\+]`, removes the character `space`, `right and left parenthesis` and the `plus sign`. Simply add all other characters you want to remove.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace all non-digits with nothing.

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A2:A4&"", "\D+",))
```

Change range to suit and/or use an open-ended range

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), regexreplace(A2:A4&"", "\D+",),))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the answer! Could you please explain what you meant by changing range to suit and/or use an open-ended range?

Comment: In the example I assumed the strings where in column A. In your spreadsheet that may not be the case. Open-ended means there is no end-row given. Example: A2:A.